# AWS EC2 spot market - run instance on a particular Availability Zone

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, blender

I'm doing some Blender rendering in the cloud using the [Brenda console](https://github.com/rider-rebooted/win_brenda_console) and Brenda. Brenda uses EC2-classic.

I'm having difficulty acquiring a reasonably-priced EC2 instance because AWS is always picking an expensive availability zone that I don't want, and thus I can never get my render started. I want the ability to choose my availability zone when rendering begins.

I'm in US-East (Virginia). When I check prices on the Brenda console, I get something that looks like this:

```
    Spot price data for instance c3.large
    us-east-1a 2017-07-22T12:28:47.000Z $0.0156
    us-east-1b 2017-07-22T12:28:47.000Z $0.0158
    us-east-1c 2017-07-22T12:28:47.000Z $0.0159
    us-east-1d 2017-07-22T12:28:47.000Z $1.05
    us-east-1e 2017-07-22T13:31:02.000Z $0.016
    us-east-1f 2017-07-22T12:28:47.000Z $1.05

    Spot price data for instance c3.xlarge
    us-east-1a 2017-07-22T09:00:40.000Z $0.0428
    us-east-1b 2017-07-22T13:04:01.000Z $0.0426
    us-east-1c 2017-07-22T12:16:19.000Z $0.0427
    us-east-1d 2017-07-22T07:12:25.000Z $2.1
    us-east-1e 2017-07-22T11:42:37.000Z $0.0436
    us-east-1f 2017-07-22T07:12:25.000Z $2.1
```

No matter which instance I pick, I want to use the availability zone us-east-1a since it's the cheapest. However, when I start a render job, I'm always ending up with us-east-1d, which is the most expensive availability zone. My $0.02 bid goes nowhere because us-east-1d's price is much higher than the other zones.

AFAIK, I cannot set up my AWS account so that it picks us-east-1a by default. (If there is a way to do that, please let me know.) It appears that I have to send over the actual availability zone when requesting my instances.

I believe I need to modify the code [here](https://github.com/jamesyonan/brenda/blob/master/brenda/run.py) at around line 39 so that I can pass in the desired availability zone. I *think* I need to do something like this, where I'm sending over the availability zone via the placement key:

```
zone = { 
    'availability_zone': 'us-east-1a',
    }
run_args = {
    'image_id'      : ami_id,
    'max_count'     : opts.n_instances,
    'instance_type' : itype,
    'user_data'     : user_data,
    'key_name'      : ssh_key_name,
    'security_groups' : sec_groups,
    'block_device_map' : bdm,
    'placement'        : zone,
    }
```

...and then later this code will make the call to AWS:

```
    ec2 = aws.get_ec2_conn(conf)
    reservation = ec2.run_instances(**run_args)
```

However, this doesn't appear to be the correct solution, as it still starts up a request for us-east-1d, the availability zone that I *don't* want.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solved it. There were two issues.

1) It turns out I was putting the availability zone code in the wrong spot in the Python script -- I was putting it in the on demand function, not the spot function. So now the availability code is actually being called.

2) My syntax was close but not correct. There was no need to create a zone object, as what was implied by Amazon's JSON documentation. Placement should have just been a string with the availability zone, like this:

```
    run_args = {
        'image_id'      : ami_id,
        'max_count'     : opts.n_instances,
        'instance_type' : itype,
        'user_data'     : user_data,
        'key_name'      : ssh_key_name,
        'security_groups' : sec_groups,
        'block_device_map' : bdm,
        'placement'        : 'us-east-1a',
    }
```

Anyway, problem solved.

Comment: Side-note: Instead of specifying an Availability Zone, you can specify a Subnet. This launches the instance into a specific subnet within a VPC. Since a subnet is created *within* an AZ, it also identifies the AZ to use.